# What is a foolproof way to make environment variables available to a script?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, jenkins, scripting, environment-variables

I have this script on an Ubuntu VM that uses an environment variable that is set in a script in `/etc/profile.d/appsetup.sh`.

The variable is used in my script, `server-up.sh`, to start my Java app:

```
export path=$KEYSTORE_PATH
java -jar -Dsecurity.keystore.path=$path [jarfile]
```

If I echo the variable, it works:

```
$ echo $KEYSTORE_PATH
/etc/ssl/certs
```

And if I run the script on my own (`sudo sh server-up.sh`) it runs and uses the environment variable just fine.

However, when the script is executed from Jenkins' "Execute Shell" step (on the same VM), it apparently can't access the environment variable, even though supposedly it's available system-wide.

I've tried setting the owner of `server-up.sh` to both `root` and `jenkins` and Jenkins runs it either way, but in neither case does it get the environment variables. In Jenkins, I also tried using the command `sudo -E /[path]/server-up.sh` but then the job fails and an error says **sudo: sorry, you are not allowed to preserve the environment**.

I've googled a dozen times for various things, but almost everything that comes up is people asking how to set environment variables in Jenkins, and I don't need to do that; I just want a script that Jenkins can execute have access to system environment variables.

What do I need to do to get this working?

Comment: There's technically no such thing as a "system-wide" environment variable. Your environment comes from one source: the process that starts your process. Environment variables are *inherited* from their parent, but changing the parent's environment after the process has been started doesn't affect the process. So the question is: what starts Jenkins, and where is `KEYSTORE_PATH` set that you believe it is system-wide?

Comment: `KEYSTORE_PATH` is exported in `/etc/profile.d/appsetup.sh`. Jenkins starts up when the VM boots up, but I can also restart it with `systemctl restart jenkins`.

Comment: Does Jenkins itself process that file, or did whatever process in its "ancestry" that would have processed that file do so before `KEYSTORE_PATH` was added?

Comment: Not sure if I'm answering the question, but there are only 2 files: `appsetup.sh` which runs automatically when I log into the VM, and the `server-up.sh` script that Jenkins calls in its job (which build the Java app first, then needs to call this script to actually start the app).

Comment: `to system environment variables.` There is no such thing. `What do I need to do to get this working?` Set environment variable in jenkins.

Comment: I didn't want to have my certificate password in there, plus have to deal with plugins and then figuring out how to pass jenkins environment variables to the VM script (unless that the "right" way to do it). What I've done for now is just use the actual values in the script itself that Jenkins calls and not use environment variables at all.

Comment: @redOctober13 : If there is kind of a bash configuration file on your host, which contains code to set the environment, you can source this file. Where is `KEYSTORE_PATH` defined? Environment variables don't suddenly spring out into existence by magic.

Comment: As stated, they're set in /etc/profile.d/appsetup.sh. After I first created that script file, I logged out of the VM, back in, and confirmed the environment variables were available.

Answer (score 1):

Make a small change to allow the `/etc/profile.d/appsetup.sh` script to output the variable to a file, where the Jenkins job can access this variable to create an environment variable available for your job to run successfully.

Comment: That seems like more work as then I'd have another file, and the Jenkins "Execute shell" script would have to read that file. My workaround was just to put the actual values of the variables in the `server-up.sh` script Jenkins calls. That way the path and password are still on the server and not in Jenkins.

Comment: This should work also, and you would not have to amend the scripts for the Jenkins job.i think It can be more simpler to read a file which is going to be replaced each time the `appsetup.sh` file is run though and not open the `server-up.sh` script to replace a variable value.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the context and needs are explained sufficiently well to properly answer the question with a here's how you do it.

On a server, jenkins.war launches from a shell (or a root shell which invokes a shell script with commands which launches jenkins), which has an environment and to which you can set and pass parameters. Those exist in the context of the jenkins.war process. If you run from a daemon (initd / systemd) you get a non-in=teractive shell, which is set differently to your normal shell.

Your Jenkins will typically have Nodes launching agents on remote servers. Those are typically launched via a non-interactive shell (so no user .profile settings).

Then the jobs themselves run on one of the agents where the executor launches a shell for the job execution. Sub-shells may be launched for specific steps.

The two context you mention `sudo sh server-up.sh` and Jenkins' "Execute Shell" step (on the same VM), **even on the same VM** do not inherit the same environment as the Node is launched on it's own process using a non-interactive shell and is not aware of anything in your `server-up.sh` script; it (generally) just gets the /etc/profile.

You have options. You can set Global variables within Jenkins:
 `${JENKINS_URL}/configure`
**Global Properties**
[ X ] Environment variables
[ X ] Prepare jobs environment (requires Env Inject plugin)

The same options also exist at the Node level

You can install the [slaves-setup plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/slave-setup/), which allows you some customization when launching agents (aka slaves).

You can install the [Environment Injector plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject), which adds the previously mentioned `Prepare jobs environment` feature.

It also adds jobs specific configuration options for:
[ X ] Prepare an environment for the run

Plus under the **Build Environment** section,
[ X ] Inject environment variables to the build process
and
[ X ] Inject passwords to the build as environment variables
Those are encrypted, and I believe are masked

Finally, you can add a build step to **Inject environment variables**, useful if you need to have different values for different steps.

---

### BUT it's certs in a keystore!

Given that you also mention what you are trying to make available is `$KEYSTORE_PATH=/etc/ssl/certs`, I wonder if you've explored using the [Credentials plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/credentials/)? Is supports a wide variety of [credential types](https://github.com/jenkinsci/credentials-plugin/blob/master/docs/user.adoc#credentials-types), including:

- Password
- Username and password
- SSH private key
- Public Certificate and private key
- Binary blob data
- That OAuth thingy

The obvious benefit to using this approach vs cooking your own is it's been designed to work securely with Jenkins so your secrets don't get inadvertently exposed. Aside from the extensive documentation on the plugin site, there's more in the book on [Using credentials](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/), using them [in a pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/) which also mentions the Snippet generator will stub it for you, and on the Cloudbees site - [Injecting secrets into builds](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci/latest/cloud-secure-guide/injecting-secrets). You can probably find plenty of help here in S/O and [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

You may also wish to explore the newly introduced [Git credentials binding for sh, bat, and powershell](https://www.jenkins.io/projects/gsoc/2021/projects/git-credentials-binding/), though not sure that's applicable in your case.

Comment: You bring up a good point about the credentials plugin. I just am concerned with complicating the setup and having to have the certificate both on the server and within Jenkins (since I need the certificate for Jenkins itself as well since it and the app Jenkins is building are on the same server).

Comment: Can't speak to your circumstances, but both [Jenkins docs](https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=135468777#content/view/135468777) and  [Cloudbees](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/203821254-How-to-install-a-new-SSL-certificate) offer cert guidance. Security iss always complicated.